# Difference in viewing a swing application via a remote client and viewing directly

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, vnc-viewer

So I have an executable jar file which when run in windows or in Linux by using the command

```
 `java -jar filename.jar`
```

the output [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRUWa.png). 
But when the same thing is viewed via a remote connection using VNC client, the output is reduced to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS5zi.png)

I have tried changing the resolution of the vncserver instance by using -geometry attribute and have also tried supplying values for "-cc" and the "-depth" attributes. But to no avail. Can someone tell me what I have to do so as to get the intended display properly in the vnc session as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be seen when the GUI is not constructed on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). The remote  connection adds enough latency to expose the underlying problem.

Because the two images have differing dialog names, verify that both represent the same code. Also, check the remote server's `.vnc` log to see what window manager is being used.

Addendum: I'm not sure what VNC server your server is using, but you may be able to edit [`$HOME/.vnc/xstartup`](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/man/vncserver.html) to specify the window manager. Gnome's Metacity has worked for me.

Comment: The same code is only used. I also found the same problem with Dialog boxes (File open and the like). I have tried alternatives like "NX" which doesn't seem to be working for some odd reason.

Comment: Plus I wanted to know if there is any solution in VNC itself.

Comment: BTW, I am using a invokeLater method as mentioned in the link that you have provided.

Comment: That leaves the server's window manager, which appears unable to supply the required peer component to the JVM.

Comment: Yes. I dont know how to overcome that though!

Answer (score 1):

VNC Clients also have settings, like color depth etc, that effect the output quality. And it also depends on capabilities of VNC. Which SErver and and which client are you using? If you have set in in the VNCSErver, check the params of VNCViewer.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant by setting the -cc and -depth attribute. I am using vnc viewer client.

Comment: You'll need to change your window manager. It seems you are using a older/primitive one like TWM etc. If that's the case you need to switch to GDM of KDM.

Comment: I will try to do that and tell you if that solved the problem. But I dont know if I will have the administrative rights to do that [is root privilege needed for it?], bcos its a remote system..

Comment: As an alternative, you can use X-protocol instead of VNC.

If your client machine is also linux/unix, you need to to xhost+ and on the machine your app is running you need to do setenv DISPLAY client:0.0 (depending on your command shell syntax).
Then launching app should show it in your client.

There exist X-Servers for windows also.